# ELB fingerprint changes continuously

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, esp8266

ELB changes fingerprint some many times on a year

My infrastructure is hosted on AWS ELB service, but they keep changing the certificate fingerprint for HTTPS. Is there a way to prevent these constant changes?

We possess a hardware component that connects through HTTPS and requires a fingerprint on .hex source code to access web services. Its complexity lies in the frequent changes of the certificate fingerprint throughout the year.

Comment: Fingerprint can only change when the cert itself does.